# Domain driven design project structure

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design, architectural-patterns

I have recently started reading about domain driven design and most of the places it's explained or discussed more in conceptual terms. Being a design philosophy it helps to understand the concepts but I was wondering how should I structure my project according to DDD.

For example in a typical structure used in most projects:

- Root

  - Presentation
  - DAL
  - Services
  - Library
  - Tests

What would be the structure of similar project in DDD? 
Do we have a public sample enterprise application which I can refer?

Comment: Maybe helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/544568/1657977

Comment: DDD doesn't have an opinion about how your project should be organized.  We get questions about folder structure all the time, but the answer is always the same: how you organize your project is *entirely up to you.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey That's like saying: How you organize your books on your shelves is entirely up to you. While that's technically true, some strategies *are* better than others, especially if you want your colleagues to be able to find anything.

Comment: @doubleYou Thanks that answer really helps.

Answer (score 5):

DDD (the Blue Book) doesn't explicitly mention project structure or a packaging hierarchy as far as I can remember. It does however make the case for using the Ubiquitous Language in our code.

It makes sense to translate that to packages too. So instead of basing your packaging on technical terms (like in your example), you could package your application based on business-terms (features).

Here is an article of mine on how to do [packaging based on functionality instead of technicalities](https://javadevguy.wordpress.com/2017/12/18/happy-packaging/).

TL;DR:

1. Packages should never depend on sub-packages.
2. Sub-packages should not introduce new concepts, just more details.
3. Packages should reflect business-concepts, not technical ones.

Comment: Actually it does! If we talk about Vaughn Vernon, he explains theory on exact code examples of a sample enterprise project with package paths.

Comment: Vaughn Vernon's examples do *not* always follow the Ubiquitous Language nor does it follow the rules mentioned above. Take a look at [the top level packages](https://github.com/VaughnVernon/IDDD_Samples/tree/master/iddd_agilepm/src/main/java/com/saasovation/agilepm). Those are not business-related.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on what the domain is about.

For example a Source Code Repository domain is interested in Change Sets, but also in files, folders, paths. There may be other interesting entities here too but already you can see a system coming together.

There is a bounded context around a specific file-system view, another around Change Sets possibly involving Commits.

The File System View could be provided in several ways, even though they all have a similar semantic in the domain. Say a View at a specific commit on a branch (implemented in terms of changes sets, commits, etc...) And a View of the local checkout (implemented in terms of the host os filesystem abstractions).

Both of those File System View implementations would be separate libraries (or at least folders in the same library with no cross dependencies). The Bounded Context of the File System View may live in its own directory.

This is essentially the idea of Onion Architecture.